# Set global navigation items through CSOM - C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, development, csom, navigation

I am trying to delete all the top navigation items from a console application, and add headers/sub items to the top navigation. I am also trying to uncheck the options to show subsites and show pages.

I found few articles talking about this, they suggest doing something like this:

```
  using(var ctx = new ClientContext("url"))
        {
            var web = ctx.Web;
            web.AllProperties["__GlobalNavigationIncludeTypes"] = "1";
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        }
```

This isn't working for me, I can't uncheck the show pages or show subsites option.

What I need to do is to clear the top navigation, then start adding links and headers. How do I achieve that from a console application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation` namespaces in CSOM API is **not supported** to modify navigation settings. for more details check [Access and Manipulate Navigation Settings via SharePoint Client Object Model](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/10/22/access-and-manipulate-navigation-settings-via-sharepoint-client-object-model/)

Now you have two option to achieve that

1. Use CSOM by using [ClientPortalNavigation.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347)
2. You have mentioned you are using console application so why you don't try to use SSOM rather than CSOM ! using SSOM you can achieve this easily and also you can find more resource about this

Below is a code via SSOM C# to achieve your goal.

**[Code]**

```
// Web Navigation
using (var site = new SPSite("http://somesite"))
using (var web= site.OpenWeb())
{
 var navigation = web.Navigation;
}

// PublishingWeb Navigation
var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);

// WebNavigationSettings
var webNavigationSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(web);
```

To uncheck the show pages or show subsites option.

```
pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = false;
pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = false;
pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentDynamicChildLimit = 20;
webNavigationSettings.Update();
pubWeb.Update();
web.Update();
```

To clear links from the Site's Navigation for each via this code

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
int id = int.Parse(topNavTreeView.SelectedNode.Value);
SPNavigationNode node = site.Navigation.GetNodeById(id);
node.Delete();
```

For more details check

- [PROGRAMMATICALLY SET NAVIGATION SETTINGS IN SHAREPOINT 2013](https://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/programmatically-set-navigation-settings-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [Customizing SharePoint Site Navigation Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh537941(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, useful hints. Regarding option 2, you ask, if the asker is to create a console application, why he does not use the SSOM. I can only assume, but probably the console application should run remotely. Just using a console application does not mean automatically that it runs on the server.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I thought but unfortunately, he didn't mention any more details about his requirements, Thank you for your valuable feedback :)