# Add a new Top Link Navigation of Site Collection to all sub sites in SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, navigation

I have around 150 sub sites in a particular SharePoint 2013 O365 Site Collection. How to add a new Top Link Navigation on all sub sites in easy way? I want to add the link of Site Collection on all these 150 sub sites without manually going to Navigation settings in each sub site.

Comment: Your subsites inherit navigation from root level or not?

Comment: No, they are not inheriting.

Comment: are you more comfortable in C# or PowerShell as we can use any of the mentioned technique to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, i read the your comment on below mentioned answer. There can be only two ways to do same (preferred). One is inherit from the parent site. If you are fine with this, then you need to update all your sub sites to inherit from root level site. Other solution will be, use Managed Metadata to create your navigation. So in all your subsite, point to the single managed metadata term store to create navigation. And a final solution (not the preferred) can be, write a script to add navigation to all the sub sites. It can be a console based application or can be a WPF based application.

Comment: Which solution you would like to go with?

Comment: Hi, I can't Inherit or use Managed Navigation as I need to retain the existing navigation settings on all sub sites which are different site to site (found by checking randomly). I need a script or any SharePoint Designer way to do this as all I need is to add this one specific link to all the sub sites without disturbing the other navigation items on them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the subsites does not inherit the topnavigation.. So you have to script it somehow. I usually use powershell with CSOM to script SharePoint online..

To connect powershell CSOM copy the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll to the scriptfolder and then connect to the sitecollection.

```
$siteUrl = <url to your sitecollection>
$username = <username>
$password = <password>
add-type -Path ".\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
add-type -Path ".\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force 
$clientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
$site = $clientContext.Site;
$clientContext.Load($site) 
$clientContext.executeQuery()
```

Then you can see this to get ideas on the rest of the script

[Set global navigation items through CSOM - C#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200935/set-global-navigation-items-through-csom-c)

The most important thing to remember is:

- Load information
- ExecuteQuery

Comment: Thanks for your response. My requirement is to add a new link to all the subsites, I don't actually find how to do it like we use "Add link" in Structural Navigation on Site Settings->Navigation page. I don't want to disturb the existing settings for Global/Current Navigation in the subsites.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform below PowerShell command :

```
if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0))
{
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
$root=Get-SPWeb "http://sp"
if($root.Webs.Count -gt 0)
 {
    foreach($web in $root.Webs)
    {
        $nodeColl = $web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar
        if($nodeColl)
         {
                    $node=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("Google", "https://www.google.com")                
                    $nodeColl.AddAsLast($node)
                    $web.Update()
        }
    }
}
$root.Dispose()
```

Comment: I have tried the above but I get "Get-SPOSite : The site xxx is not properly formed." error.

Comment: Mine is SharePoint Online site, that's why I have used Get-SPOSite and tried using SharePoint Online Management Shell. But still no luck

Answer (score 0):

if your links need to be displayed on all pages you can add them to the master page